# Illegal Construction in Anaconda or Miniconda

Tags: anaconda

When I try to install either of them, I encounter a message like this
`Miniconda3-py39_22.11.1-1-Linux-aarch64.sh: line 412: 10882 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) "$CONDA_EXEC" constructor --prefix "$PREFIX" --extract-conda-pkgs` 
How can I resolve it ?

Comment: Is this being run on an Arm-based system?

Comment: I have been told that Arm based is compatible with AARCH64.

Comment: So long as you’re using an ARMv8 ISA, that’s correct. I was asking because there’s no information about your hardware, making it difficult to know where to start asking questions 